# SwiftUI: DatePicker/Date() formating

Tags: swift, swiftui, datepicker, format

I have a .sheet element, that acts as a form when a user is adding to a calendar. Everything works as expected, but as soon as they submit, and upload the Date, Start Time, and end time into firebase where it's held, I noticed a problem. The date and time were formated weird.

My question is, how can I change the var scheduledate to a mm/dd/yy format when stored, and how can I change the var starttime and var endtime to a h:mm format when stored.

Here's my code:

```
struct SheetView: View {

var userEmail = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email
@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
@State private var scheduledate = Date() //Store this as mm/dd/yy
@State private var startTime = Date() //Store this as h:mm
@State private var endTime = Date() //Store this as h:mm
@State private var scheduleairplane = ""
@State private var scheduleinstructor = ""

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack {
            Text("New Flight")
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
            Spacer()
            Button("Cancel") {
                dismiss()
            }
            
        }
        .padding()
        VStack {
            DatePicker("Date", selection: $scheduledate, displayedComponents: .date)
                .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
                .frame(maxHeight: 400)
            DatePicker("Start Time", selection: $startTime, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
                .padding(.leading)
            DatePicker("End Time", selection: $endTime, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
                .padding(.leading)
        }
        VStack {
            TextField("Airplane...", text: self.$scheduleairplane)
                .padding([.leading, .trailing])
                .offset(x: 10)
                .frame(height: 30)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                        .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 1)
                        .padding([.leading, .trailing])
                )
            TextField("Instructor...", text: self.$scheduleinstructor)
                .padding([.leading, .trailing])
                .offset(x: 10)
                .frame(height: 30)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                        .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 1)
                        .padding([.leading, .trailing])
                )
        }
        
        Spacer(minLength: 0)
        Button(action: {
            let doc = db.collection("Scheduled").document("\(userEmail ?? "Error")")

            // Atomically add a new region to the "regions" array field.
            doc.updateData([
                "Airplanes": FieldValue.arrayUnion(["\(scheduleairplane)"])
            ])
            doc.updateData([
                "Date": FieldValue.arrayUnion(["\(scheduledate)"])
            ])
            doc.updateData([
                "Time": FieldValue.arrayUnion(["\(ScheduledTime)"])
            ])
            doc.updateData([
                "Instructor": FieldValue.arrayUnion(["\(scheduleinstructor)"])
            ])
        }) {
            Text("Submit")
        }
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .frame(width: 120, height: 45)
        .background(Color("Blue"))
        .cornerRadius(30)
        .padding(.bottom)
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend against doing this. A `Date()` represents a specific moment in time. As soon as you change the formatting, you are losing information. For example, it looks like you're dealing with flights - what are you doing about time zones? Why do you have three items of data (a day and two times) when what you're really dealing with is a `DateInterval`?

Comment: I've never used firebase but I'd be extremely surprised if it didn't have a native column type for storing dates. What do you mean by "weird formatting"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the help but I found an answer
[here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-convert-dates-and-times-to-a-string-using-dateformatter) that works very well and is easy.

I used 3 different functions that I ran when I click the button. Then I send them off to firebase with the new values.

```
func updateDate() {
let selecteddate = scheduleddate //Here it gets the date and saves as another variable
let formatter1 = DateFormatter()
formatter1.dateStyle = .short
//I then made a saved string called newscheduledate to use this new variable anywhere in my project.
newscheduledate = formatter1.string(from: selecteddate) //Here is when it sets the conversion to a string which I used when I sent to firebase.
}
```

I then used this piece of code below twice, for the start time, and the end time.

```
func updateTime() {
let selectedtime = startTime //Here it gets the date
let formatter2 = DateFormatter()
formatter2.timeStyle = .medium
//I have a saved string called newstarttime to use this new variable anywhere in my project.
newstarttime = formatter2.string(from: selectedtime)
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
class GeneralExtension{
    static func DateToStr(date:Date,format:String = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")->String{
        let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
        timeFormatter.locale = Locale.current 
        timeFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current 
        timeFormatter.dateFormat = format
        let nowTimestr = timeFormatter.string(from: date)
        return nowTimestr
    }
    static func StrToDate(dateStr:String,format:String = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")->Date{
        var cbDate:Date = Date()
        if(!dateStr.isEmpty){
            let dateFormatter=DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat=format
            let tmpDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr)
            if let tmpDate = tmpDate{
                cbDate = tmpDate
            }
        }
        return cbDate
    }   
}
```

example

```
GeneralExtension.DateToStr(date: dateSetting,format: "MM")
```

or

```
extension String{
    func StrToDate(format:String = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")->Date{
        var cbDate:Date = Date()
        if(!self.isEmpty){
            let dateFormatter=DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat=format
            let tmpDate = dateFormatter.date(from: self)
            if let tmpDate = tmpDate{
                cbDate = tmpDate
            }
        }
        return cbDate
    }
}

extension Date{
    func DateToStr(format:String = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")->String{
        let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
        timeFormatter.locale = Locale.current
        timeFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        timeFormatter.dateFormat = format
        
        let nowTimestr = timeFormatter.string(from: self)
        return nowTimestr
    }
}
```

example

```
let date = Date()
let dateStr = date.DateToStr("MM")
let convertDate = dateStr.StrToDate()
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response, I hope this works. Quick question though since I'm a pretty new programmer. 1. Where do I put these functions, just under the struct I assume? 2. When and how should I go about running them? If you could, could you put it in the code in the Q to make it 10000 times easier?